# LWC - Passing ID to Apex Method treated as a String not ID

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass the current id to my apex method but keep running into the following error.

```
message":"Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'caseID' of type 'Id'
```

**My LWC is wrapped in a LC and used as a quick action**

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void getStatusCase(ID caseID){
    System.debug('here id: ' + caseID);
}
```

JS:

```
@api recordId;
handleClick(event) {
    updateStatusCase({ caseID: '$recordId'})
            .then(result => {
                window.console.log("updated");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                window.console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });   
}
```

I believe it is treating the recordid as a string and not ID.

Comment: @M guy in apex, the ```Id``` can be the type of ```Id``` or ```String```.
Where are you using your component? is it on record page?

Comment: It is wrapped in a LC and used as a quick action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your component is used as a quick action, you should wrap it in an aura component

```
<aura:component
    implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
    access="global">

    <c:aQuickActionLWC recordId="{!v.recordId}"></c:aQuickActionLWC>
</aura:component>
```

then in your LWC define a `@api recordId` propriety.

Comment: Perfect thank you

Comment: You 're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Calling Apex imperatively (using a Promise) does not support dynamic variables, as far as I know. Only the Wire service. Since your use case cannot use a Wire (DML inside the Apex call), you should send the recordId in its standard form, not as a dynamic variable:

```
updateStatusCase({ caseID: this.recordId})
```

Comment: Its treating it as null in my apex method

Comment: Make sure your component's meta XML file is set to associate the component with a specific record. Add this:
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>

Comment: Yes lightning__RecordPage is there in my xml. Could the issue be because it is wrapped in a LC?

Answer (score 0):

> How about passing the api variable in the following notation.

```
  @api recordId;
    handleClick(event) {
          updateStatusCase({ caseID: '$recordId'})
                .then(result => {
                    window.console.log("updated");
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    window.console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                });   
    }

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void getStatusCase(String caseID){
    System.debug('here id: ' + caseID);
}
```

Comment: Its treating it as null in my apex method

Comment: I have imported LightningElement and api. I thought @api recordId automatically got the id from the current record page. So all I needed to do is pass it to my apex method. Not sure why its null

Comment: So use the same signature as Original Post   updateStatusCase({ caseID: '$recordId'}) , In Apex Method declare the variable as a String

Comment: I have. The only line I changed was that one to updateStatusCase({ caseID: this.recordId})

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I get the following output: $recordId. Seems it is treating it as a string. Edited the question as It is wrapped in a LC and used as a quick action